# Find out if certain column differs within a group pyspark dataframe

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

so I am wondering if there is a nice way to compare the values of a column within a group and for example put a new column to that group if those values are not all the same.

Little example df:

| name | sex |
| --- | --- |
| Anna | female |
| Sam | male |
| Sam | female |
| Anna | female |

And what I want:

| name | sex | difference |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Anna | female | True |
| Sam | male | False |
| Sam | female | False |
| Anna | female | True |

The grouping above would be by name and then the entries under sex should be compared.
Unfortunately the "entries"- in this example a string (male, female)- is an simplification. In my real data it can be a string, a number, a date ... whatever. So a working solution has to compare in a general way if the entries in a certain column are the same per group.

I'd like to state an idea of a solution but I have absolutely no clue how to achieve this...any ideas are appreciated :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can check whether the number of unique elements is equal to 1 for each group of names:

```
from pyspark.sql import functions as F, Window

df2 = df.withColumn(
    'difference',
    F.size(F.collect_set('sex').over(Window.partitionBy('name'))) == 1
)

df2.show()
+----+------+----------+
|name|   sex|difference|
+----+------+----------+
|Anna|female|      true|
|Anna|female|      true|
| Sam|  male|     false|
| Sam|female|     false|
+----+------+----------+
```